# Uploading a huge SQL file

Tags: mysql, large-files, file-transfer

I have a 3 huge 5GB .sql files which I need to upload to my server so I can process it. Its too large to run on my computer so I can't process the information offline.

So the question, How can I upload a huge 5GB sql file to MySql server without using PHP because its upload limit is 2MB.

The MySql is hosted on a remote server miles away so I can't just plug it in but I have turned remote access on which should be of some help.

All ideas welcome.
Thank-you for your time
Paul

Comment: have you access to remote terminal? i.e. ssh and rsync?

Comment: It might be less hassle to burn the data on DVDs and ship it off to the hosting company - although they'll probably charge you to copy the data onto your box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PHP to import such huge files. You need to use command prompt to do so. If you have access to the server then it's quite easy to do so. You can login to the server through `SecureCRT`(paid) or [`putty`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)(free).

Use this command to import the sql database to the server - Using IP Address

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 databasename < data.sql
```

OR - Using hostname

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h mysql.hosting.com database-name < data.sql
```

If you wanna try it out locally first to get used to the command prompt. You can use this.

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost data-base-name < data.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like phpMyAdmin? If you have ftp/sftp access upload the file and then run it with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In my experience, most hosting companies limit (quite rightly) the amount of time a PHP script may take.  Loading 5GB of .sql (even if the file is local) could well exceed the script timeout.

Comment: I think phpMyAdmin allows you to select a local mysql file and processes it asynchronously (outside the request). It's been a while but I remember handling some pretty large sql file with it. Also from the phrasing of the question it sounds like he's on a dedicated server but that's not clear.